# Hired by company abroad

Tags: united-states, taxes, limited-liability-company, business, sweden

Can I work directly for a company abroad (Sweden) in the United States if they do not have a U.S. entity and I'm a U.S. citizen? Or should I set up an LLC and function as a consulting business?

Answer (score 4):

It's very easy. No need for an LLC. I'm in a similar situation. The only thing I've asked of my (Irish) employer is that they issue me with a [1099-MISC](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-1099-misc-miscellaneous-income) form in time for tax season.

It will mean you'll have to sort our your taxes yourself (pay estimated taxes and pay an additional payroll tax) as well as deal with benefits (e.g. health insurance).

But it works fine for me, and has for over 7 years.

I recommend finding a good accountant to help you with it.

Comment: Thanks Peter, what do you do for expense reimbursement (travel, etc)

Comment: @JoshuaLee, please make that a separate question.

Comment: You should talk to someone in the payroll department in Sweden and find out if you need to pay any Swedish taxes, and to make sure they're not withholding taxes you don't need to pay.

Comment: Just TBC, you absolutely **do not especially need a 1099**.  I never bother with them.  And don't forget, even if you want one, don't even ask for it from the Swedish company until the end of this year.

Comment: You probably need to pay estimated taxes each quarter too.

Comment: @Fattie : True, but it helps me put my taxes together.

Comment: @Kevin : Yes, that's what I was implying with `sort our your taxes yourself`. Estimated taxes is what I do.